# Error in retrieving data from Sqlite

Tags: android

I want to retrieve a data from database, Also the the restaurant id should be sorted in ascending order, I tried retrieving data using the query. Somebody please help me, I really cant find whats wrong

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + key_id_cart + " as _id,  "
            +" ORDER BY "+ restaurant_ID +  " DESC"+", " + restaurant_name + ", "
            + restaurant_thumbnail + ", " + dishname + ", " + dish_image
            + ", " + AreaId + ", " + ItemChoiceIds + ", " + ItemChoiceQty
            + ", " + ItemId + ", " + Quantity + " from "
            + tablenameCartData, new String[] {});
```

The problem is it returns an exception as follows

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  key_id_cart as _id,   ORDER BY restaurant_ID DESC, restaurant_name, restaurant_thumbnail, dishname, dish_image, AreaId, ItemChoiceIds, ItemChoiceQty, ItemId, Quantity from tablenameCartData
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your query to following
`Order by` should always come to end of the query it is giving that error because of the `,` it is getting before `order by`

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + key_id_cart + " as _id,"
            + restaurant_name + ", " + restaurant_ID + "as res_id,"
            + restaurant_thumbnail + ", " + dishname + ", " + dish_image
            + ", " + AreaId + ", " + ItemChoiceIds + ", " + ItemChoiceQty
            + ", " + ItemId + ", " + Quantity + " from "
            + tablenameCartData + " ORDER BY res_id DESC", new String[] {});
```

Comment: I tried this code Now I am getting an exception like....................     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: i think there is a problem with query make sure all the columns that you have written in query are matching with the table structure. This error usually occurs when the column that you specify doesnt exists in table.

Comment: @Geethu these exceptions occurred while trying to fetch primitive values ( int, long ) from the Cursor. So if your try to read value that may be null/empty so cursor throws these kind of exception.solution to these exception is you should always add default values to primitive nullable columns at the creation point.

Comment: Ya I tried, I am able to fetch the data but the ordering is not happening

Comment: try doing order by with alias... I have edited my answer pls check

Answer (score 2):

Add `ORDER BY` after `tablenameCartData` name or in the end of select query as:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + key_id_cart + " as _id,  "
            + restaurant_ID +  " "+", " + restaurant_name + ", "
            + restaurant_thumbnail + ", " + dishname + ", " + dish_image
            + ", " + AreaId + ", " + ItemChoiceIds + ", " + ItemChoiceQty
            + ", " + ItemId + ", " + Quantity + " from "
            + tablenameCartData+" ORDER BY <COLUMN_NAME> DESC", new String[] {});
```

Where `COLUMN_NAME` is name of column by which want to order query response

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong in the SQL query :

Correct syntax is :

> SELECT column-list
>
> FROM table_name
>
> [WHERE condition]
>
> [ORDER BY column1, column2, .. columnN] [ASC | DESC];

Code should be : 

`Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + key_id_cart + "as _id"+ " from "
+ tablenameCartData + " ORDER BY "+ restaurant_ID +  " DESC"+", " + restaurant_name + ", " + restaurant_thumbnail + ", " + dishname + ", " + dish_image + ", " + AreaId + ", " + ItemChoiceIds + ", " + ItemChoiceQty
+ ", " + ItemId + ", " + Quantity +" DESC" , new String[] {});`

Answer (score 1):

An enhanced version (using **bound parameters** and **less string concatenations**):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery
(
    "SELECT ? as _id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? from " + 
    tablenameCartData + " ORDER BY ? DESC", 
    new String[] 
    {
        key_id_cart, restaurant_ID, restaurant_name, restaurant_thumbnail,
        dishname, dish_image, AreaId, ItemChoiceQty, ItemId, Quantity,
        COLUMN_NAME
     }
);
```